# TYPO3 9.5 - need help: fe_users convert old md5 passwords

Tags: passwords, migration, typo3, md5, typo3-9.x

In older TYPO3 versions (<9.5) the fe_user passwords in MD5 where converted live when logging in by the extension salted_passwords.

Now I still have some fe_user passwords in MD5 but the salted_password extension does not exist anymore. When an fe_user tries to login with md5 I get the error:

> No implementation found to handle given hash. This happens if the
> stored hash uses a mechanism not supported by current server. Follow
> the wiki link to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the earlier version of TYPO3 8.x (AFAIK, In TYPO3 9.x scheduler task no longer exist because it uses different algos!), you will have the option to convert user passwords to salted hashes.

Did you missed that?

- Go to `Scheduler` module in the `System`
- Add new task called `Convert user passwords to salted hashes`
- Run!

See:[image]

You got to go!!

Answer (score 1):

Would it be an option to write a Scheduler Task that converts old MD5 passwords?
This task could be kept on the system just in case, and be used when required.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for the answers which are all correct I think.
Finally I did it like that:

Switched back to TYPO8.7 and imported the fe_users still having md5.
Then run scheduler task (by the way: I miss this task in TYPO 9.5 - maybe this has to do with salted_passwords migrated into the core ?).

**One important notice:** the scheduler task will convert all Passwords including those who already have argon2 ! So its important to only convert the ones with md5.

Then reimported the migrated users to 9.5 via phpMyadmin.

Thanks a lot for all replies.